# SQL query: how to check existence of *multiple* rows and columns with one query

Tags: mysql, sql, set

Given the following table:

```
SET   VAL1   VAL2
-----------------
1      a      a1
1      b      b1    
1      c      c1
2      d      d2
2      e      e2
```

Is it possible to create a query which identifies a subset of rows with particular values for columns VAL1 and VAL2 and identical values in column SET?

In contrast to the similar example with 2 columns we can not use IN here (as far as I see) because the combinations of VAL1 and VAL2 values are not arbitrary but given.

The expected output would be for

```
VAL1 = a and VAL2 = a1 and VAL1 = b and VAL2 = b1 and VAL1 = c and VAL2 = c1  => 1
```

And for

```
VAL1 = d and VAL2 = d2 and VAL1 = e and VAL2 = e2 => 2
```

And for

```
VAL1 = d and VAL2 = d2 and VAL1 = e and VAL2 = f => null
```

The Problem is, that I can not use something like:

```
SELECT SET
FROM MyTable
WHERE VAL1 IN (a, b, c) AND VAL2 IN (a1, b1, c1)
```

because it would not pay respect to particular rows and give false positives on constellations like:

```
SET   VAL1   VAL2
-----------------
1      c      a1
1      a      b1    
1      b      c1
2      e      d2
2      d      e2
```

Comment: expected output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would help us helping you!

Comment: Seems to be a *Relational Division*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, [*`IN` can be used to compare row constructors*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
WHERE (val1, val2) IN (
    ('a', 'a1'),
    ('b', 'b1'),
    ('c', 'c1')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `group by` and `having`.

```
select `set`
from tbl
group by `set`
having sum((VAL1 = 'a' and VAL2 = 'a1') or (VAL1 = 'b' and VAL2 = 'b1') or (VAL1 = 'c' and VAL2 = 'c1')) = 3
```